# Why Is My Caesar Cipher Code Skipping Over Some Characters?

Tags: javascript, string, caesar-cipher

I have the code below for a Caesar Cipher to increment by 13 characters on each input character. It works for almost all inputs, but will seemingly skip over random chacaters. I just can't seem to figure out why?! I'm still learning, so any help would be fantastic!

The input is a coded string of characters that will be output with each character shifted forward 13 places. The expected output should be a readable string.

If I input rot13('GUR DHVPX OEBJA SBK WHZCF BIRE GUR YNML QBT.') I would expect 'THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.' But instead I get 'T H E   Q U I C K   B R O W N   F B X   J H M P S   B V R E   G U R   L A Z Y   D B G .'

I appreciate this could be a duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer to this particular problem so far.

```js
function rot13(str) {
  
  let newStr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let charNum = str.charCodeAt(i);
    console.log(charNum);
    if (charNum > 64 && charNum < 78) {
      let res = str.replace(str[i], String.fromCharCode(charNum + 13));
      newStr.push(res[i]);
    } else if (charNum > 77 && charNum < 91) {
      let res = str.replace(str[i], String.fromCharCode(charNum - 13));
      newStr.push(res[i]);
    } else {
      newStr.push(str[i]);
    }
  }

  console.log(newStr);
  return newStr.join(" ");
}

rot13('GUR DHVPX OEBJA SBK WHZCF BIRE GUR YNML QBT.');
```

Comment: Play computer on pen and paper and understand exactly what you're telling the computer to do (or step through the code in the debugger, but I recommend the manual approach when starting out so you're forced to *really* understand what's happening). Think about what your code is actually doing every time through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.fromCharCode(charNum + 13)` & `String.fromCharCode(charNum - 13)` are all you need. You don't need to replace the char at index `i` in `str`.

```
newStr.push(String.fromCharCode(charNum + 13));
newStr.push(String.fromCharCode(charNum - 13));
```

Comment: This was awesome and worked perfectly. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your second condition:

```
let res = str.replace(str[i], String.fromCharCode(charNum - 13));
```

But even without that your code is over engineered. A bit modified version

```
function rot13(str) {
  let newStr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let charNum = str.charCodeAt(i);
    //console.log(charNum);
    if (charNum > 64 && charNum < 78) {
      let res = String.fromCharCode(charNum + 13);
      newStr.push(res);
    } else if (charNum > 77 && charNum < 91) {
      let t = charNum + 13 - "Z".charCodeAt(0);
      let res = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) - 1 + t);
      newStr.push(res);
    } else {
      newStr.push(str[i]);
    }
  }

  return newStr.join(" ");
}
```

There are even better solutions, but for beginner this should do it.